# How to find if the value contains characters

Tags: python

Right now am planning to add items into the database. The item name, price and all are all entered by the users. How do I find if theres any alphabets when entering the price? i tried using .isnumber() but it seems to be reading my decimal point as a character as well.

```
while True:
        itemPrice = input("Please Enter Item Price: ")
        if str(itemPrice).isnumeric()  == False:
            print("Please enter a value!")
        else:
            print(itemPrice)
            break
```

For example, they allow if i enter 5 but not 5.5 and since this is item price it should have decimals.

Comment: Easiest way is to convert it to a `float` and see if it fails.

Comment: if you would type your requirements, and criteria so we can work on them.

Comment: Is `1e2` valid?

Comment: isnumeric tells if all characters are numerical characters. Not if the string is a numerical string. Note that ``½`` or ``³`` are numerical characters. '.' is not. So ``"5.5".isnumeric()`` is False, while ``"5½³₄2".isnumeric()`` is True

Answer (score 3):

You can catch exceptions,

```
while True:
    itemPrice = input("Please Enter Item Price: ")
    try:
        itemPrice = float(itemPrice)
        print(itemPrice)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a value!")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use try/except block

```
a = 3.5345
a=str(a)

try: #if it can be converted to a float, it's true
    float(a) 
    print(True)
except: # it it can't be converted to a float, it's false
    print(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a for loop to check:

```
def containsAlpha(x):
    if True in [char.isalpha() for char in x]:
        return True
    return False

while True:
    itemPrice = input("Please Enter Item Price: ")

    if containsAlpha(itemPrice):
        print("Please enter a value!")
    else:
        print(itemPrice)
        break
```